# How to use GraphQL response as a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, axios, graphql

I am new to GraphQL and I am have the query working as expected but I am having trouble working with the response.

#### Query

```
query {
  all_assets(where: {title: "suppliestile-blt9607aa6a28539d2e.zip"}) {
    items {
      url
    }
  }
}
```

#### Calling Response

```
var jsondata = JSON.stringify(response.data);

console.log(jsondata);
```

This is giving me the following response

```json
{"data":{"all_assets":{"items":[{"url":"https://assets.contentstack.io/v3/assets/blt15ad871ba49b8a41/blta52af33b959c061f/6352b5fb3bd922566d8d3f2d/suppliestile-blt9607aa6a28539d2e.zip"}]}}}
```

Essentially I would like to use the url value as a variable moving forward but I am having trouble extracting it from all of the nested objects and arrays does anyone have any advice to get me pointed in the right direction?

Comment: It's _already_ a variable, `jsondata`. It's not clear why you're turning it _back_ into a JSON string, though. Working with objects and arrays is a basic JS task, I'd recommend running through an introductory tutorial like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript#tutorials

Answer (score 0):

The answer won't differ because it's a Graphql request. It's just a response that you get through the request via **`response.data`**.

If you need to access specific object/property within the response , you need to use the index of the object, you can do

```
const url = response.data.all_assets.items[0].url;
```

Comment: As @jonrsharpe points out, the OP doesn't even need to stringify the response as it's already an object. He can access the properties directly.

Comment: you are right, did not notice the JSON.stringify part